# No close icon when viewing an image

Tags: support, ios-app, images

I opened an image displayed in a question. It opened and it was possible to zoom in and out.

But you have to zoom completely back to get out of this view. There is no close (X) icon or something else to get out of the image view.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "Close" button; you can control it all with gestures...

A single tap will close the image, regardless of the current zoom.

In its natural zoomed out state, you can swipe the image off screen.

A double tap will also switch between a zoomed in and zoomed out state, so you can (if already zoomed in) double tap (to zoom out) then swipe to close the image.